# Am unable to launch any website using webdriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I was trying to launch any website using the python selenium module.

First, I installed python selenium-2.31.0 module, and then I tried running the following script.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

But it is showing the below error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\Backups\Backups\D drive\Softwares\eclipse-galileo\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_1.4.6.2788\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 881, in <module>
    debugger.run(setup['file'], None, None)
  File "D:\Backups\Backups\D drive\Softwares\eclipse-galileo\plugins\org.python.pydev.debug_1.4.6.2788\pysrc\pydevd.py", line 710, in run
    execfile(file, globals, locals) #execute the script
  File "D:\eclipse_workspace\Python_Test\src\TimeSheet_fill.py", line 4, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Firefox()
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.31.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 59, in __init__
    desired_capabilities=capabilities)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.31.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 67, in __init__
    self.start_session(desired_capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.31.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 109, in start_session
    'desiredCapabilities': desired_capabilities,
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.31.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 160, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Python26\lib\site-packages\selenium-2.31.0-py2.6.egg\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 127, in check_response
    raise exception_class(value)
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message:
Exception AttributeError: "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'print_exc'" in <bound method Popen.__del__ of <subprocess.Popen object at 0x02C6C0F0>> ignored
```

What is wrong in my script, and what I should do to launch the website?

Comment: Any particular reason you're using 2.31? The newest version on PyPI (as reported by pip) is 2.35.

Comment: Your script looks correct. So there must be something wrong with your environment. Can you start firefox from a cmd shell?

Comment: Check the firefox version, if it is more than 20 and onward, it is not supported by selenium-2.31.0.

Comment: Now, I am using 2.35 module and the Firefox version is 22. I am able to run firefox from the cmd shell path. Im still getting the same error.